# Custom font for my Android app not showing up on physical device

Tags: android, typeface, android-typeface

I've tried a bunch of things, like setting the font on a layout level, creating a typeface and setting it, and cleaning and rebuilding the project. The font will show up in the editor, and last I was able to try it, the emulator (though my computer hasn't been the greatest lately), but not my Samsung Galaxy Note 3. Here's the Java code:

`

```
package com.example.benkyoblobandroid;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BlobView extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton pet;
    Group infoGroup;
    ImageButton studyTimeButton;
    TextView HPLabel;
    TextView EXPLabel;
    TextView EXP;
    TextView lvl;
    Typeface pixelFont;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        HPLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HP);
        EXPLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EXPLabel);
        EXP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EXP);
        lvl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lvl);
        pixelFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "font/fff_forward_regular");
        HPLabel.setTypeface(pixelFont);
        EXPLabel.setTypeface(pixelFont);
        EXP.setTypeface(pixelFont);
        lvl.setTypeface(pixelFont);
        pet = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pet);
        infoGroup = (Group) findViewById(R.id.infoGroup);
        pet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                infoGroup.setVisibility(infoGroup.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
        studyTimeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.studyTimeButton);
        studyTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switchActivity(StudyTimeView.class);
            }
        });
    }

    void switchActivity(Class activity) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, activity);
        startActivity(activityIntent);
    }
}`
```

And the XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlobView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blob_room" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="Pet"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/slimepet_pink" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.40" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flashcard" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/infoGroup"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="info,infoText,EXPStar,lvl"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="185dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="246dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/leftInfoGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/topInfoGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.23" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomInfoGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.43" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/rightInfoGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/midInfoGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.31" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomInfoGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightInfoGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftInfoGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topInfoGuideline">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/happiness"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/HP"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/health1"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/health_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/health2"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/health_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/health3"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/health_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/health4"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/health_empty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/health5"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/health_empty" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/expInfo"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomInfoGuideline"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftInfoGuideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/happiness"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/midInfoGuideline">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EXPLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font"
                android:text="@string/exp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EXP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font"
                android:text="@string/EXP"
                android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/starStartGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/EXPStar"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/starStartGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/midInfoGuideline"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exp_star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lvl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/EXPStar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/EXPStar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/EXPStar"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="350sp"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iconsTop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/leftInfoGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/rightInfoGuideline">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/studyTimeButton"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ui_01_study_time_light_with_colored_shadow"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp"
            android:contentDescription="Study Time"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/iconsTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Attached are how it looks in the editor vs. how it looks on my Android, and also the file hierarchy. [Font works in editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr8gN.png)[Font does not work on device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U1Zw.jpg)[Fonts in the file hierarchy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3hT.png)

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 was released in 2013, which is old. I would just create a simple 'hello world' app using your font to see if it renders on your old device.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource which shows how to set up an xml resource for the font.

Comment: My expectation would be that the device is so old it doesn't support that type of font.  Font support was increased over time, and that device is ancient.

Comment: but why are you trying to set it programmatically by adding it in assets?. Instead you should add it under ```res\font\``` and then use the xml property ```android:fontFamily="@font/customfont"```. And if still the problem arises then as @Gabe Sechan said its a realyy old device and might not support the font you are using.

Comment: @Laser That ability didn't come to Android until like SDK 10.  Back with the Note 3 you couldn't set it in XML.  Fonts were a big PITA in those days.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ohh i didn't knew that...its been an year since i started working on android.